# Assign numpy matrix to pandas columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have dataframe with 48870 `rows` and calculated embeddings with shape `(48870, 768)`

I wanna assign this embeddings to padnas column
When i try

```
test['original_text_embeddings'] = embeddings
```

I have an error: `Wrong number of items passed 768, placement implies 1`
I know if a make something like df.loc['original_text_embeddings'] =  embeddings[0] will work but i need to automate this process

Comment: try assigning `list(embeddings)`.  This breaks the array into 1d pieces, which can be assigned to column cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataframe/column needs a 1d list/array:

```
In [84]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [85]: pd.Series(x)
...
ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Splitting the array into a list (of arrays):

```
In [86]: pd.Series(list(x))
Out[86]: 
0      [0, 1, 2, 3]
1      [4, 5, 6, 7]
2    [8, 9, 10, 11]
dtype: object
In [87]: _.to_numpy()
Out[87]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your embeddings have 768 columns, which would translate to equally 768 columns in a data frame. You are trying to assign all columns from the embeddings to just one column in the data frame, which is not possible.

What you could do is generating a new data frame from the embeddings and concatenate the test df with the embedding df

```
embedding_df = pd.DataFrame(embeddings)

test = pd.concat([test, embedding_df], axis=1)
```

Have a look at the documentation for handling indexes and concatenating on different axis:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html